# How to show parent and its child when filtering Extjs Treepanel parentNode

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, treepanel

How to Show childNodes in extjs treePanel if parent Node is filtered

[Fiddle Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1num)

As you can see the fiddle you can filter any parent Node but child will be hidden,
but when you search child parent will be visible.

I want to see parent in the both the cases.
Either filtering child/parent always parent should be there.
if child filtered respective parent stay there , this is already there in extjs

Answer (score 4):

You need to add code to the filter function, so it also checks parent nodes.

In the filterFn, `if (!visible) {` add:

```
var parent = node.parentNode;
var testVisible = false;
while(parent){
    testVisible = v.test(parent.get('text'))

    if(testVisible){
        visible = testVisible;
        break;
    }
    parent = parent.parentNode;
}
```

Fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1oso

Answer (score 1):

You can check if current node parents are valid by adding this right after you check if the nodes' children validate:

```
if (!visible) {
    var current = node;
    while (current.parentNode) {
        current = current.parentNode;
        if (v.test(current.get('text'))) {
            visible = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1osn&view/editor).